# why does my form only accept .jpeg files

Tags: php, forms, upload

I made this form:

```
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="php/handler.php" method="post" name="uploaderform">
    <table>
    <tr><td align="right">File:</td><td><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000"/><input type="file" name="filetoup" id="zzz"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="right">Folder:</td><td><select id="category" name="category"><option value="foo/">some</option><option value="poo/">some2</option></select></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td></tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```

and this PHP script:

```
if((exif_imagetype($_FILES["filetoup"]["tmp_name"])==IMAGETYPE_GIF)
||(exif_imagetype($_FILES["filetoup"]["tmp_name"])==IMAGETYPE_JPEG)
||(exif_imagetype($_FILES["filetoup"]["tmp_name"])==IMAGETYPE_PNG)
&&($_FILES["filetoup"]["size"]<2000000)){
if($_FILES["filetoup"]["error"]>0)
    echo $_FILES["filetoup"]["error"];
else {

    if(isset($_FILES["filetoup"]["name"]))
        $target_path=$folder . basename($_FILES["filetoup"]["name"]);
    else
        echo "Choose a file";

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filetoup"]["tmp_name"],$target_path))
        echo $_FILES["filetoup"]["name"] . "uploaded";
    else
        echo "Either you fucked up or I did";
    }
 }else{
echo "read whats under the form";
 }
```

and I can only upload .jpeg files, .gif and .png are not accepted and I get this error:

```
Warning: exif_imagetype() [function.exif-imagetype]: Filename cannot be empty in      C:\xampp\htdocs\atthepc\php\handler.php on line 7
```

I think that it's something from my form, because I can upload .jpeg without any errors but .gif and .png not. If I'm not right, what then is causing this? And is there a solution or am I doing everything wrong?

And finally, are .jpg recognized as .jpeg's?

/edit

i dont think i explained myself correctly, if i try to upload a jpeg file, it works fine but if i try any other file type it gives me  Filename cannot be empty in , so my form doesnt want to accept the gif and send it through post, its like the post is empty. why is thsi happening?

//edit
and yes that is it,  i tried this

```
$something=$_FILES["filetoup"]["tmp_name"];
var_dump($something);
```

and it gives me string(0) "" . the form doesnt want to accept it but why? i did not put any restriction in the form.

///edit

i found my problem, it was not accepting any other file type because what i was trying to upload was too big(animated gif) and the max_file_size was too little.

Comment: .jpg is 3 letter extension, abbreviation of JPEG, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try comparing type with an IF statement instead of tmp_name with exif_imagetype? $_FILES["filetoup"]["type"])==IMAGETYPE_GIF

Also, re JPEG, [w3schools.com mentions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) that:"Note: For IE to recognize jpg files the type must be pjpeg, for FireFox it must be jpeg." so maybe that's something to look into

Comment: Furthermore `$_FILES[ 'somefile' ][ 'type' ]` is an unreliable way to determine the actual mime type of the file. It can be forged. Not sure what is currently actually considered the most reliable way of determining a file's mime type in PHP though. For images though, you are able to test whether it actually is an image with `getimagesize( $filename )`, which will return false on failure (and generate an `E_WARNING`). It's a hack to circumvent mime type detection, but it does the job for images.

Comment: "Not sure what is currently actually considered the most reliable way of determining a file's mime type in PHP though." Ha, I missed the use of `exif_imagetype` in OP's question. Maybe that's a reliable way...

Answer (score 0):

use a switch case insted of all the if's and set the $target_path in the case for each jpeg, png and gif, if they needs to be in different folders.. and make the default as an error if tmp image file aint allowed..

just one way to do it, hope it helps